# IntersectionObserver doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

Hello everyone I'm using simple intersectionObserver code for sliding content in from bottom by adding class. It works fine in any other browser and on mobiles but Safari. I can't find information what should I change or do to make it work. Any help please

```js
const slideInContents = container.querySelectorAll('.slide-in')

  const showOptions = {
    root:null,
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: " 0% 0% -10% 0%"
  };
  const showOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function (
      entries, showOnScroll) {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
          return;
        } else {
          entry.target.classList.add('show');
          showOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      })
    },
    showOptions);
  slideInContents.forEach(slideInContent => {
    showOnScroll.observe(slideInContent)
  })
```

It's just the example but when I will have all the content ready it  will look something like that with small changes maybe. By the way all this content is simply invisible.

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
      <div class="scroll one">

        <video autoplay playsinline muted loop="true" preload="auto" poster="./images/socialmedia/media-S.jpg">
          <source src="./video/cel2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>


        <img class="hero slide-in from-bottom" src="./images/6.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="flower">

        <div class="slide-in from-bottom page-text">
          
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
            Corrupti nobis ipsamcupiditate, a dolorem similique quaer 
            non, in cum
            pariatur!
          </p>
        </div>

        <video class="slide-in from-bottom" autoplay muted loop="true" playsinline preload="auto">
        <source src="./video/cel2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>


        <img class="slide-in from-bottom hero" src="/src/images/7.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="flower">
```

Comment: May you also share the html?

Comment: sure, will add it now

Comment: it doesn't allow me to put more code but its just a few more elements down

Comment: Please check if it is compatible:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#browser_compatibility

Comment: Are you by any change on macOS Sierra or lower version? Then it's not compatible. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=IntersectionObserver)

Comment: i have available two versions of safari 12 and 14 on older macbook and newer Imac , anyway It's sorted out ,the problem was **showOptions**, I got rid of it completely  from the code and it works in both versions , is intersecting.